# Are there any accounts of famous Mathematicians/Scientists and their dogs, or any pets in general?

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, depiction-of-scientists

I know this is probably a precise and odd question, but I'm curious to know if any famous Mathematicians or Scientist had pets. I'm really looking for Mathematicians and dogs but I thought it better to widen my search.

Comment: off-topic: Edward Albee just passed away, RIP.   Search for "The Goat, or Who is Sylvia"?

Comment: I think that this question is off-topic,cf. [this meta post](http://meta.hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-questions-about-mathematicians-and-scientists-lives-on-topic).

Comment: It's well known that Von Neumann had a dog named Inverse.

Comment: +1 because dogs

Answer (score 4):

F. D. C. Willard co-authored a paper with Jack Hetherington. Willard was his cat.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F.D.C._Willard